# When NFS Client try to create a file on shared folder, operation not permitted occurs, both server and client are in containers

Tags: linux, docker, containers, nfs, kind

I've googled a lot and found some similar cases. However, none of them works in my case. Not sure if it has something to do with Mac.

I will try to describe my question as clearly as possible.

- I use KIND to run a local Kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes. I mount a volume in the master node `/data/k8s` from my local MacOS `/tmp/k8s`
- I create a NFS Server on the master node, export `/data/k8s`
- I also install NFS on the slave node as NFS Client, and mount master node `/data/k8s` to my the slave node local `/data/k8s`

and here is the problem:

- Everything works well on master node, no problem.
- On slave node, I `CANNOT` create a regular file while I CAN create a folder
- On slave node, I `CAN` revise any files created on master node
- Any files created on master node would sync without problems on slave node.

and here is some information:

- The OS (Both master and slave are identical)

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.10 (Eoan Ermine)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

- mount information on master node (The space is initially mounted from host MacOS)

```
root@test2-control-plane:/data/k8s# mount | grep /data
grpcfuse on /data/k8s type fuse.grpcfuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,max_read=1048576)
```

- exports setting on master node

```
/data/k8s/ *(fsid=0,rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

- etab information on master node

```
*(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,no_pnfs,fsid=0,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

- permission information on master node

```
root@test2-control-plane:/data/k8s# ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root  224 Dec 25 01:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dec 24 12:33 ..
```

- mount information on slave node

```
root@test2-worker:/data/k8s# mount | grep /data
172.18.0.4:/data/k8s on /data/k8s type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=172.18.0.4,mountvers=3,mountport=45257,mountproto=udp,local_lock=all,addr=172.18.0.4)
```

- permission information on slave node

```
root@test2-worker:/data/k8s# ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root  256 Dec 25 02:17 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 4096 Dec 24 13:23 ..
```

- What I've tried:

  - I've checked SELinux

  ```
  root@test2-control-plane:/data/k8s# sestatus
  SELinux status:                 disabled
  ```

  - I've tried to add `all_squash` and add `anonuid` and `anongid` with a specific user, and I define the user with identical user_id and group_id on both master node and slave node. And then switch to the defined user on my slave node.
  - Have tried so many that I can't remember them all.

I know it may be a specific case. If anyone could help will be so so much appreciated.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.